# Json Marshalling straight to stdout

Tags: json, go

I am trying to learn Golang and while doing that I wrote below code (part of bigger self learning project) and took the code review from strangers, one of the comment was, "*you could have marshalled this straight to stdout, instead of marshalling to heap, then converting to string and then streaming it to stdout*"

I have gone through the documentation of [`encoding/json`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json) package and [`io`](https://pkg.go.dev/io) but not able to piece together the change which is required.

Any pointers or help would be great.

```
    // Marshal the struct with proper tab indent so it can be readable
    b, err := json.MarshalIndent(res, "", "    ")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(errors.Wrap(err, "error marshaling response data"))
    }

    // Print the output to the stdout
    fmt.Fprint(os.Stdout, string(b))
```

**EDIT**

I just found below code sample in documentation:

```
    var out bytes.Buffer
    json.Indent(&out, b, "=", "\t")
    out.WriteTo(os.Stdout)
```

But again it writes to heap first before writing to `stdout`. It does remove one step of converting it to string though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create and use a [`json.Encoder`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Encoder) directed to [`os.Stdout`](https://pkg.go.dev/os#Stdout). [`json.NewEncoder()`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#NewEncoder) accepts any [`io.Writer`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#Writer) as its destination.

```
res := map[string]interface{}{
    "one": 1,
    "two": "twotwo",
}

if err := json.NewEncoder(os.Stdout).Encode(res); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

This will output (directly to Stdout):

```
{"one":1,"two":"twotwo"}
```

If you want to set indentation, use its [`Encoder.SetIndent()`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Encoder.SetIndent) method:

```
enc := json.NewEncoder(os.Stdout)
enc.SetIndent("", "  ")
if err := enc.Encode(res); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

This will output:

```
{
  "one": 1,
  "two": "twotwo"
}
```

Try the examples on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/LY0RWyrT6r4).